# iOS binaries not working (dyld: could not load inserted library)

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I am using a jailbroken iPhone 6 on iOS 9.2.

I have installed proxychains from [here](http://apt.thebigboss.org/onepackage.php?bundleid=me.qusic.proxychains) via Cydia and created a simple proxychains.conf file (containing `http  10.0.0.5 8080`) in the current folder.

I then try and run a command such as: `proxychains4 -f proxychains.conf openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443`

I get the following error:

```
[proxychains] config file found: proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
dyld: could not load inserted library '/usr/lib/libproxychains4.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/lib/libproxychains4.dylib: mmap() error 22 at address=0x0017D000, size=0x00001000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libproxychains4.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I get the same error trying to run anything from proxychains, e.g. `proxychains4 -f proxychains.conf ping 8.8.8.8`

I then tried installing the version of proxychains from here (http:// cydia.radare.org/debs/) via Cydia and basically the same thing hapens

I separately installed GnuTLS from here (http:// apt.saurik.com/dists/tangelo/main/binary-iphoneos-arm/Packages) also via Cydia and when I try and run it `gnutls-cli`, I get a very similar error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libgnutls.26.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/gnutls-cli
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/lib/libgnutls.26.dylib: mmap() error 22 at address=0x001B1000, size=0x00005000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libgnutls.26.dylib
        /usr/lib/libgnutls.26.dylib: mmap() error 22 at address=0x00269000, size=0x00005000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/libgnutls.26.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: It hasn't been updated since 2015, so it's likely just not supported on iOS 9.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson , Are you refering to both proxychains and GnuTLS? They both seem to have a similar issue in two different applications,

Comment: Yes, they're both old. There have been a lot of things that changed, so it's normal for these things to stop working. This same error occurs for other things that don't work on iOS 9.